# Javascript function only works in edge not chrome, firefox or opera

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to make a js function that works on all browser. I'm using the following function to press a button when user clicks enter and are clicked into a textbox(asp)

This javascript function only works in edge but not chrome, firefox or opera:

```
function button_click(objTextBox, objBtnID) {
    if (window.event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById(objBtnID).focus();
        document.getElementById(objBtnID).click();
    }
}
```

cs code:

```
Password.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "button_click(this,'" + LogIn.ClientID + "')");
```

Any advice in cross-browser support?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `window.event.keyCode` is non-standard. The event should be passed to the `button_click` function.

Comment: not trying to be that guy, just trying to cover all bases: you have a syntax error in the code posted, as it is missing a final curly brace

Comment: In a click event handler the `event` object is `MouseEvent` not a `KeyboardEvent` Mouse events object don't have a `keyCode` property. Hence `event.keyCode === undefined` No clue what shenanigans Edge is doing to give you a keyCode. Also see [**KeyboardEvent.keyCode Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) for alternatives as `keyCode` is deprecated.

Comment: While `window.event` is non-standard, everyone except Firefox supports it. You haven't described what doesn't work. Are there errors in the developer console? Have you done any logging or other debugging?

Comment: @CrazyTrain It just does nothing in chrome, and works as intended in edge. No errors or anything like that.

Comment: @Ragnar How are you debugging? What do you mean `does nothing`? Does the code trigger at all? Add a `console.log(event)` and `console.log(event.keyCode)`  to the top of your function before the if statement to see if the code triggers at all in Chrome and to check the values you get if it does trigger. If the event isn't bound at all and the code isn't triggered at all you need to look at possible issue of ASP.NET not binding the event correctly in Chrome.

Comment: @Nope Well the console.log() is problematic since i have a weird bug that makes pressing enter redirect me to a different page which clears the console, i have not written any code for this purpose. This might be the reason for the problems in the first place. I'm honestly pretty lost.

Comment: @Nope i also tried keyboardeventEvent.keyCode, which visual studio just comments off without giving me any errors.

Comment: I think i figured it out, the function did trigger in chrome and edge but pressing enter makes another click event trigger for some reason which redirects me. So pressing tab then enter works. Edge does the function first chrome presses another button first. If anyone have a suggestion to fix this it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Ragnar To test the console.log code just hit any key when focusing on the input box, like a,b,c etc.., ENTER can trigger submits when within a form I believe. Might be a property on from what I remember that can disable ENTER as submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are using asp.net. You can use this example in html code to select a default button that will be activated by pressing enter

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="LogIn">
        <p class="InfoText">Username:</p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <p class="InfoText">Password:</p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
```

Hope this helps.